# Adding React Template to React js error

Tags: reactjs, react-templates

I am new working with ReactJs, i am using React Js with React-templates, i followed the basic guide in the proyect documentation but i get an error that i don't know how to solve

Codepen !
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVKEqj

- I am using gulp, browserify.
- using "gulp-react-templates" for compiling react templates into js, "commonjs" mode

This is the error
            `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: ReactCompositeComponent.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

Here is my code

- app.jsx

  ```
  var React = require('react/addons');
  // I supouse instance my "title" template 
  var Title = require('./templates/title.rt.js');

  var App = React.createClass({
      render:function(){
          // It should be use the template -_-
          return Title

          // i tried it and works, i copied the content of "title.rt.js"
          // return React.createElement('h1', {}, '\n\tHola esto es react template\n');
          // this works too
          // return (React.createElement('h1', {}, '\n\tHola esto es react template\n'));
      }
  });
  var element = React.createElement(App, {});
  React.render(element, document.querySelector('.container'));
  ```
- title.rt.js < title.rt template compiled in js using "gulp-react-templates" "commonjs"

  ```
  'use strict';
   var React = require('react/addons');
   var _ = require('lodash');
  module.exports = function () {
      return React.createElement('h1', {}, '\n\tHola esto es react template\n');
  };
  ```
- Gulp for React Template

  ```
  gulp.task('rt', function() {
                  gulp.src('./src/rt/**/*.rt')
                      .pipe(rt({modules: 'commonjs'}))
                      .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/jsx/templates'));
              });
  ```
- Gulp for Jsx

  ```
          function build(file){
              if (file) {
                  gutil.log("Recompiling: "+file);
              }
              return bundler
                  .bundle()
                  .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil,'Browserify Error'))
                  .pipe(source('main.js'))
                  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/assets/js'));
          }
          var bundler = watchify(browserify({
              entries:['./src/jsx/app.jsx'],
              extensions:['.jsx'],
              debug:true,
              cache:{},
              packageCache:{},
              fullPaths:true
          }));
          bundler.on('update',build);

          gulp.task('jsx', function(){
              build();
          })
  ```

Thank for any help

#

The solution

```
   var App = React.createClass({
      render: Title
   });
```

Daaaan, i was toooo many hours on this.

Comment: Yeaaaahh !!!
After 5 hours dealing with it i found the solution.

    `var App = React.createClass({
    render: Title
    });`

Comment: Nice job! Figuring out those little details can be tough sometimes. Mark this as closed if you no longer need assistance

Comment: @RollRodrig why are you not using ES6?